# In R, a rolling Standard Deviation that can skip over NA values?

Tags: r, standard-deviation, rolling-computation

I am wondering if there are any fast R functions that can compute a rolling Standard Deviation on a vector, while skipping over any NA values in the middle of said vector, so the vector still lines up with the original data?

The package `TTR` has `runSD` but it returns an error if there is NA in the middle of the vector.

The package `fTrading` has `rollVar` which has `na.rm=TRUE`. Taking the square root of the rolling variance gives the standard deviation. However, it actually deletes the NA values, which means that the rolling standard deviation no longer lines up with the original data.

Or, is there a way to temporarily remove the NA values, then insert them back when the calculation is done?

**Update**

See [Re-inserting NAs into a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3908831/re-inserting-nas-into-a-vector).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Re-inserting NAs into a vector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3908831/re-inserting-nas-into-a-vector)

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
library(zoo)
set.seed(1)
x <- sample(c(1:3, NA), replace = TRUE, size = 10)
r <- rollapply(data = x, width = 3, FUN = sd, fill = NA)
r
```

Comment: Brilliant, this seems to work well.

Comment: Glad to hear that it worked. But you won't get much of a `sd` with window width of 1.

Comment: Yes, I realized this, and changed my comment :)

Answer (score 0):

The code below seems to work well.

Calculate the result using `na.omit(X)`, then insert the NA values back in using the function below. The code below uses square root, however you can use any function including `runSD`.

```
# Inserts NA back into result, based on a "template" (a vector with existing NA values)
ReNA <- function(NAtemplate,result) 
{
    NAtemplate[!is.na(NAtemplate)]<-result;NAtemplate
}

X=c(4,9,NA,16,NA)
X    
[1]  4 9 NA 16 NA
result <- sqrt(na.omit(X))
X=ReNA(X,result)
X
[1]  2 3 NA 4 NA
# These values are the square root of the previous, with NA values inserted back in.
```